# F# docker application: A function labeled with the 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file....?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, f#, .net-core

### The issue can be easily reproduced by creating a new project from scratch.

The Visual Studio version is V15.7.5. I created a new F# .Net core 2.1 application with docker support (Linux). However, it got the following error.

> A function labeled with the 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file in the compilation sequence.

The following is the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 64890
EXPOSE 44390

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication8/WebApplication8.fsproj WebApplication8/
RUN dotnet restore WebApplication8/WebApplication8.fsproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication8
RUN dotnet build WebApplication8.fsproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApplication8.fsproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication8.dll"]
```

And the following is the `Program.fs`

```
namespace WebApplication8

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

module Program =
    let exitCode = 0

    let CreateWebHostBuilder args =
        WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()
        exitCode
```

**.fsproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <UserSecretsId>b379991e-83d8-444e-b888-62e9ac139864</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Controllers/ValuesController.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Dockerfile" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Full errors,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: docker-compose, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "name=dockercompose15479956486365536117_webapplication8_" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
1>e95714bd0022
1>docker exec -i e95714bd0022 /bin/bash -c "if PID=$(pidof -x dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
1>c:\source\repos\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\WebApplication8.fsproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
1>c:\source\repos\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\Program.fs(22,9): error FS0433: A function labeled with the 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file in the compilation sequence.
1>Done building project "WebApplication8.fsproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**start.fs generated by VS**

```
namespace WebApplication8

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

type Startup private () =
    new (configuration: IConfiguration) as this =
        Startup() then
        this.Configuration <- configuration

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1) |> ignore

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IHostingEnvironment) =
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) then
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
        else
            app.UseHsts() |> ignore

        app.UseHttpsRedirection() |> ignore
        app.UseMvc() |> ignore

    member val Configuration : IConfiguration = null with get, set
```

**value.fs generated by VS**

```
namespace WebApplication8.Controllers

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

[<Route("api/[controller]")>]
[<ApiController>]
type ValuesController () =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    [<HttpGet>]
    member this.Get() =
        let values = [|"value1"; "value2"|]
        ActionResult<string[]>(values)

    [<HttpGet("{id}")>]
    member this.Get(id:int) =
        let value = "value"
        ActionResult<string>(value)

    [<HttpPost>]
    member this.Post([<FromBody>] value:string) =
        ()

    [<HttpPut("{id}")>]
    member this.Put(id:int, [<FromBody>] value:string ) =
        ()

    [<HttpDelete("{id}")>]
    member this.Delete(id:int) =
        ()
```

Comment: You'll have to show your `WebApplication8.fsproj` file.

Comment: I've shown the `.fsproj` file in the question.

Comment: Ok, then you also need to show `Startup.fs` and `ValuesController.fs`. Also, the full text of the error wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I've posted all the three files/messages. The files are generated by Visual Studio and not modified.

Comment: The error message refers to `Program.fs` line 22, but the content of `Program.fs` that you posted only has 13 lines. Do you have a different `Program.fs` somewhere? Have you not posted the whole content?

Comment: Line 22 is `let main args =`. I didn't post the `open ...` part of the `Program.fs`.

Comment: Are you saying that the module `Program` is not the top-level module in that file? Please post the whole `Program.fs` file.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full `Program.fs`. It has an extra namespace (scaffolded by visual studio)

Answer (score 4):

The UserSecretsId tag in .fsproj is causing the problem, because the .net core compiler is generating code for it in the wrong place. The solution is to remove the tag and add it inside a separate assemblyinfo.fs file:

```
module Your.Namespace.AssemblyInfo

open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets

[<assembly: UserSecretsIdAttribute(“b379991e-83d8-444e-b888-62e9ac139864”)>]

do()
```

For a more detailed description  of the problem and the workaround see this article: [Making ASP.NET Core User Secrets Work in F# Projects](https://medium.com/@dmytrol/making-asp-net-core-user-secrets-work-in-f-projects-9b04572d81f6)

Comment: This put me on the right path. With Visual Studio 15.8, User Secrets infest your fsproj file automatically. I deleted the extension from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core, removed the UserSecretsId and published again - all good!

Comment: Indeed, this was the cause

Answer (score 3):

Add `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>` will do the trick.

As in :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `WebApplication8.fsproj` file and make sure that `Program.fs` is the last file listed in the `.fsproj`. (That's what the phrase "the last file in the compilation sequence" in the error message is referring to). In F#, unlike C#, order *matters* in the project file: later files are allowed to use functions and classes from earlier files, but not vice-versa. This restriction helps discourage circular dependencies: they're allowed in F#, but they are required to be in the same file, which prevents them from getting too large. See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/ for further discussion of this issue.

But to solve your problem right now, do what the error message says and make sure `Program.fs` is listed last in `WebApplication8.fsproj`, and that should make it work.

Comment: The file is generated by visual studio and I didn't change it. I will check it when I have a chance later.

Comment: If it was generated by Visual Studio, it might have the files listed in alphabetical order, because that's the common convention for C#. But alphabetical-order listing doesn't work for F#.

Comment: I've added the `.fsproj` in the question. It seems the `Program.fs` is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

In the full test of `Program.fs` that you have posted, the very last declaration appears to be `exitCode`, not `main`:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()



exitCode  // <-- this is the last thing in the module
```

So the compiler complains, quite naturally, that the last thing in the module is not the `main` function. To fix, indent the `exitCode` line, so that it is inside the `main` function:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()
    exitCode
```

Comment: Sorry, the layout messed up when copying the code from Visual Studio to SO (Maybe Visual studio generated some tab instead of spaces). The two lines are aligned. I've fixed the question. It will get compile error if they are not aligned.